# como conectar el puerto a una vb y implementar la funcion

Tags: python, mvc, odoo

Estoy implementando una bascula al modelo de odoo que estoy creando pero no me deja hacer la funcion que quiero ya que necesito que la información que imprime la bascula necesito pasarla a la vista del modelo pero cuando hago toda la funcion en el archivo python y actualizo el modulo me manda un error porque el puerto de comunicacion no lo encuentra que podria hacer ahi

Adjunto codigo:

````
```# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import fields, api, models
import logging
import serial

puerto = ""
baudrate =9600

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Bascula (models.Model):

_name=('mti_bascula')

vendor_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Provedor')
category_supplier_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner.category', string='Category Supplier', default=lambda self: self.env.ref('mti_assured.mti_assured_category_Carrier'))

vendor_mti_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Provedor.')
category_supplier_mti_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner.category', string='Category Supplier Mti', default=lambda self: self.env.ref('mti_assured.mti_assured_category_suppliers_mti') )

driver_mti_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Operador.')
driver_truck_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mti.fleet.operator', string='Operador')

number_plate = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mti.fleet', string='Placas Trac.')
num_plate_mti_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='fleet.vehicle', string='Placas')

consignment_note = fields.Char(string='Carta Porte')

destiny = fields.Char(stirng='Destino')

VIA = fields.Selection(selection=[
    ('Aereo', 'Aereo'),
    ('Maritimo', 'Maritimo'),
    ('Terrestre', 'Terrestre'),

], string='Via')

partner_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Remitente')

peso_id = fields.One2many(
    comodel_name='peso_detalle',
    inverse_name='peso_id',
    string='Detalles',
)

consignee_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Consignatario')
category_consignee_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner.category', string='Category Consigne',default=lambda self: self.env.ref('mti_assured.mti_assured_category_consignee'))

receive = fields.Char(string='Recive')

seller_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='hr.employee',string='Ejecutivo')

Commodity = fields.Char(string='Mercancia')

gross_weight = fields.Integer('Peso Bruto', digits='Product Price')

def peso(self):
    ser = serial.Serial(port=puerto, baudrate=baudrate)
    ser.write(b'peso')
    ser.close()



  class DetallePeso (models.Model):

_name = ('peso_detalle')

peso_id = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='mti_bascula',
    string='Peso',
)

Ancho = fields.Integer(string='Ancho')
Alto = fields.Integer(string='Alto')
Volumen = fields.Integer(string='Volumen')
Peso_Bruto = fields.Integer(string='Peso_Bruto')
Descripcion = fields.Char(string='Descripcion')
Palletizado = fields.Selection(selection=[
    ('Si', 'Si'),
    ('No', 'No'),
], string='Palletizado')
Emplayado = fields.Selection(selection=[
    ('Si', 'Si'),
    ('No', 'No'),
], string='Emplayado')
Flejado = fields.Selection(selection=[
    ('Si', 'Si'),
    ('No', 'No'),
], string='Flejado')
Sello = fields.Selection(selection=[
    ('Si', 'Si'),
    ('No', 'No'),
], string='Sello')```
````

cabe mencionar que la funcion se va a ejecutar cuando presione un boton por eso inclui la funcion del boton y lo que puse ahi y tambien que estoy probando todo esto desde una maquina virtual como podria corregir el error que me se esta mandando porque la conexion en el equipo fisico lo pone en el puerto 6 y en ma aquina virtual lo reconoce de otra manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi lo reconoce en la maquina virtual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ese es el error que manda en la terminal como tendria que hacer la conexion para la vb o que tendria que hacer en el codigo para qyue no mande error y me imprima la informacion de la bascula

Comment: El puerto com1 son para equipos windows.

Comment: a ok en este caso estoy usando ubuntu que puedo hacer ahi?

Comment: Toca  investigar. Se que odoo facilita eso ahora con las cajas IoT, pero no he tenido experiencia con ellas

Comment: hice otra pregunta respecto a otro modulo dentro del proyecto de odoo no se si me puedas ayudar @Legna